# How can I determine which ftp server is running on my ubuntu box

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, ftp

I can access my ubuntu box via ftp with username root and the same password I use for root ssh access.

I can't seem to ftp into the box with other usernames that are fine via ssh.
I've tried looking for files like .vsftpd in /etc/ but no joy as yet, am I barking up the right tree?

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can run sudo lsof to look at all the open files (which includes sockets) and find out which application uses TCP port 21 and/or 22.

Comment: Awesome, this worked a treat

Answer (score 12):

The command `netstat -tanp` will show you what PID is associated with what port, look for a line like this to find what daemon is LISTENing on port 21:

```
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1450/sshd
```

But of course with port number 21 and not 22 (21 for ftp). Then you can use `dpkg -S <binary>` to see what package is providing it. `<binary>` is the name of the daemon on the last column of netstat, after the PID.

Answer (score 6):

`telnet ip.addr.of.host ftp`

You'll probably get a link that starts with 220 with the software name and version. For vsftpd:

```
220 (vsFTPd 2.0.4)
```

Comment: It's more accurate to say you *might* get a 220 that includes the name of the software.  Some servers don't, for reasons of "security".

Comment: Yes, you're right, but as long as he's not aware of any ftp daemons running, it's probably a normal version of a daemon.

Answer (score 6):

Here's a "fun" way to do this.  First you have to install dpkg-awk.

```
dpkg-awk 'Status:installed' 'Provides:ftp-server' -- Package
```

Translation: match on packages that are installed and that provide the ftp-server metapackage.  Of those, print only the Package: line.

Comment: That's a cool one.

Answer (score 2):

Type `ftp` and then `status`. The version and which ftp service is used will display as follows:

```
ftp> status
Not connected.
No proxy connection.
Gate ftp: off, server (none), port ftpgate.
Passive mode: on; fallback to active mode: on.
Mode: ; Type: ; Form: ; Structure: .
Verbose: on; Bell: off; Prompting: on; Globbing: on.
Store unique: off; Receive unique: off.
Preserve modification times: on.
Case: off; CR stripping: on.
Ntrans: off.
Nmap: off.
Hash mark printing: off; Mark count: 1024; Progress bar: on.
Get transfer rate throttle: off; maximum: 0; increment 1024.
Put transfer rate throttle: off; maximum: 0; increment 1024.
Socket buffer sizes: send 16384, receive 87380.
Use of PORT cmds: on.
Use of EPSV/EPRT cmds for IPv4: on.
Use of EPSV/EPRT cmds for IPv6: on.
Command line editing: on.
Version: tnftp 20100108
ftp>
```

`tnftp` is uses in my case . In addition you see all options set. Exit with `quit`.

Comment: vsftp does not seem to report itself this way.

Comment: executing "ftp" executes your local ftp client, not the server. This does not show anything about your server as you are not connected.

Answer (score 0):

I just went to my `/etc` folder in Ubuntu and did `ll | grep ftp` and saw that I have some `vsftp` related files. Then I typed `service vsftp status` and it was indeed running:

```
buttle@ubuntu-/etc$ service vsftpd status
vsftpd start/running, process 728
```